# VB.NET- Peformance when testing an empty string

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, vb6

In VB6, I was told that when testing for an empty string, it would be much faster to check this by verifying the length of the string by using :

```
If Len("ABC") = 0 then 'fast
```

or

```
If LenB("ABC") = 0 then 'even faster
```

instead of:

```
If "ABC" = "" then 'slower
```

Do you know by any chance if this is true also in VB.NET? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't exactly the syntax for VB but in C# you can use the String static method `IsNullOrEmpty`:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty("ABC")
```

When you are debugging this method, it will check on the .Length of the parameter. Checking on Length is always faster because on String compare, the compiler must create a new object to compare (in this case a "ABC" string).

Comment: Are you saying that the IsNullOrEmpty is faster than .length?

Comment: No. If you're debug this function, you will see that the .NET Framework use .length instead of comparing with an empty String.

Comment: It's not really relevant whether it uses length:  MS may change that implementation in a future patch.  What's more important is that this is the _correct_ way to do the test.  It might be a smidgen slower now and then, but I seriously doubt empty string checks are a bottleneck in your app.

Comment: let's say the string is null - would checking only the length then throw an exception? If so, I guess it's probably safer to use "String.IsNullOrEmpty"

Comment: Doing str.Length when str is Nothing will throw an error. The IsNullOrEmpty function is the proper way to do this.

Comment: The speed issue is vastly outweighed by the readability. These types of optimizations are a waste of time rare exceptions. Even if one way does happen to be slightly faster, that can change in future versions of the compiler. That is not part of the contract between the compiler and developer.

Answer (score 5):

It's not necessary no, I mean are you kidding me? How many people write programs where comparing a string to see if it is zero length has any impact at all on performance. Even if strings didn't retain a length count and VB did a c-style strcmp() string comparison every time, it doesn't take a string comparison function very long to work out that one of the strings is zero length does it? But .NET strings do include a length field and so when you do a string comparison the first thing it's going to check is if the lengths differ, i.e. a straight int comparison. All you save by doing this yourself if a function call and then only if the JIT inlines Len().

By the way, in VB.NET you don't need to call String.IsNullOrEmpty() because comparisons between strings are transformed into a call to String.strcmp() which transforms nulls (Nothing in VB) into references to String.EmptyString. It then goes on to call a native function that Reflector can't examine, but I'd be pretty sure that the first thing it does is check if the lengths of the strings differ.

Comment: I'm with you. These types of premature optimizations are silly. I wouldn't even consider doing something like this unless you were in an extremely time critical app that is running an empty string check millions of times over. Even then it is questionable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
If ("Value").Length > 0 Then

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the the best solution for a VB6 equivalent to IsNullOrEmpty is

```
Public Function IsNullOrEmpty(ByRef s As Variant) As Boolean

  If IsNull(s) Then ' IsNull returns true if s is a Variant that is Null
    IsNullOrEmpty = True ' IsNull returns false if s is a Variant and s = vbEmpty
    Exit Function
  End If

  If LenB(s) = 0 Then ' never compare a string to "" - it's slow
    IsNullOrEmpty = True
    Exit Function
  End If

  If LenB(Trim(s)) = 0 Then
    IsNullOrEmpty = True
    Exit Function
  End If

  IsNullOrEmpty = False

End Function
```

Ironically, if you have strings or variant that are set to vbEmpty, then this function will return false, because vbEmpty as string is "0". So if you are not careful using this version you could get some strange errors.